# Intersection between multiple files

Tags: python, file

I have multiple files (say3).  Each file has only one column. Looks like following:

File A

```
America
Russia
China
UK
```

File B

```
India
China
Russia
```

File C

```
China
America
Russia
Iran
```

Now, for computing the intersection or say to get the common elements in all files, I do

```
python -c 'import sys;print "".join(sorted(set.intersection(*[set(open(a).readlines()) for a in sys.argv[1:]])))' File1 File2 File3 File4
```

But, if I also need to know the pairwise overlap between these file, how can I loop the process? so that I get a set of elements that are present in all of them and also the elements that are present in A&B, A&C, c&B.

Help in python will be appreciated.

Kindly help

Comment: why do you have to do this with the `-c` option? Just write a script. Use argparse if you need complex command line functionality.

Comment: How about an example, please.

Comment: Why the downvote? anyone? Please tell me so I can improve or delete my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get lines that are common to all files you can use:

```
for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    data = []
    with open(f) as inp:
           lines = set(line.rstrip() for line in  inp)
           data.append(lines)
    common_lines = data[0].intersection(*data[1:])
```

For the second part use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

for f1, f2 in combinations(sys.argv[1:], 2):
    with open(f1) as inp1, open(f2) as inp2:
        print set(line.rstrip() for line in inp1).intersection(map(str.rstrip,
                                                                           inp2))
```

Comment: There is a typo: `sys.argv` instead of `sys.srgv`

Comment: Hi! I have read all my files in through a parser. Something like this, featurefile = [x.strip() for x in options.featurefiles.split(",")]     Now all my file names are in variable featurefile, how can I use this as an input. Please help.

Comment: @Angelo What does `featurefile` contains. File names or the data inside the files?

Comment: It contains file names. BTW your first code is throwing up an error. Have you checked it? here is the error common_lines = data[0].intersection(*data[1:])
                                                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: @Angelo Sorry about the indentation, it's fixed now. Simply use `featurefile` instead of `sys.argv[1:]` then.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `set` for that:

```
>>> print list(set(open(f1)) & set(open(f2)) & set(open(f3)))
```

For specific files, you can do:

```
>>> print list(set(open(f1)) & set(open(f2)))
>>> print list(set(open(f1)) & set(open(f3)))
>>> print list(set(open(f2)) & set(open(f3)))
```

As per @HerrActress's suggestion, this will take care of the `\n` part of the string:

`[i.strip() for i in (set(open(f1)) & set(open(f2)))]`

Comment: It's probable answer, isn't it?

Comment: @GoodGJ, What does that mean? I do not understand

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either. Ideally, you'd strip newlines, but the OP's example doesn't do that, so I think it's a good answer.

Comment: First, I didn't give you minus but plus. I meant your ans. is pretty good for this problem.

Comment: @sshashank124: Just to clear, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: You are hardcoding file objects here, that could be one reason for the downvotes.(I am not the downvoter)

Comment: This is a great one-liner. If the OP wants to remove the newlines also: `[i.strip() for i in (set(open(f1)) & set(open(f2)))]`

Comment: @sshashank124 Sorry for posting that but it did not work as expected that's why i deleted the comment. I have posted the correct variant above (tested).

Comment: @HerrActress. Updated again. Thank you so much for your addition.